# Reframing a HMM problem as an RNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, hidden-markov-model

Inspired by [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282987/hidden-markov-model-vs-recurrent-neural-network) I have been considering how one would reframe a HMM problem as RNN problem.

For HMMs we have some observable timeseries $y(t)$ which corresponds to a set of hidden states $q(t)$. The transition probabilities between hidden states are described by a probability matrix $\bar{A}$. For a Markov process, it is possible to derive an expression for the probability that the hidden path $Q$ corresponds to the observation $O$ i.e. $P(Q|O)$. One can then use some optimisation algorithm -e.g. [Viterbi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) to find the most probable path $Q*$ which maximises $P(Q|O)$.

But **how does this formulation translate to an RNN?**

With RNNs we talk in the language of training data, nodes, layers etc. and I can't see how to map this to the HMM language...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hidden nodes (states) in an HMM are random variables, while in an RNN only the input nodes could be considered random variables, all the other nodes are just deterministic nonlinear functions.

Thus, it is difficult to formulate an HMM with an RNN. However, some attempts have been made to combine the ideas of dynamic Bayesian networks (DBNs), of which HMMs would be examples, and neural networks, e.g. the [VRRN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02216), [alpha-nets](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/016763939090049F), or [GenHMM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.05744). How much those still resemble vanilla RNNs or DBNs is up for discussion.

Comment: "_It is difficult to formulate an HMM with an RNN_". Ok I can see that, and agree, but can we _solve_ similar problems, as suggested by the linked question and e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70420/97992 ?

Answer (score 3):

Neural networks can be used to amortize the optimization part, effectively learning an adaptive solution given a corpus of data.
The connection with VAEs is pretty easy to see here.

So, in your notation, instead of optimizing for $Q*$, you would learn an approximate posterior.

See the *Structured Inference Networks* and *Deep Markov Models* presented in:

> R. G. Krishnan, U. Shalit, and D. Sontag, *“Structured Inference Networks for Nonlinear State Space Models.”* 31st AAAI Conference on Artificial Intelligence, AAAI, 2017. doi: 10.48550/ARXIV.1609.09869.